# Regex for timestamps in the first 5 minutes after the hour

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a log file for a process that logs every 5 minutes, but not at an exact minutes/seconds and I want to find the first log message of each hour. A sample line looks like:

```
2013-01-01 09:03:55 foo bar some log message foo bar
```

What would be the regex to use with `grep` to extract those first-of-the-hour lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
grep "[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:0[0-5]" logfile
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use grep to get only the single first line for each hour since it doesn't keep state between matches. Something like this would get all lines in e.g. the first five minutes every hour:

```
grep '\d\d:0[0-5]:\d\d' logfile
```

You can get just the first entry from the first five minutes every hour with awk:

```
awk -F'[ :]' 'BEGIN {hh=-1} $2!=hh && $3>=0 && $3<5 {hh=$2; print}' test
```